# MongoDB collection.aggregrate accept only two arguments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying the aggregation in mongoose. When I run that aggregation, it show the error. What am I missing?

```
 const data = await Rooms.aggregate([{ $match: { adminID: "1234" } }]);
```

Error is like that

```
MongoInvalidArgumentError: Method "collection.aggregate()" accepts at most two arguments
```

Edit -- code for Rooms Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Rooms = new mongoose.Schema(
{adminID: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },  
roomID: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },  
roomName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },  
users: [
        {
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                unique: true,
            },
        },
    ],
},
{ timestamps: true } );
```

module.exports = mongoose.model("rooms", Rooms);

Comment: show `Rooms` definition

Comment: @Anatoly I added Schema in post

Comment: @Anatoly I got it. I think it is mongoose 6.0.4 bug. When I downgrade to 5.13 it run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1 : downgrade mongoose to version 5

solution 2 :

```
const data = await Rooms.aggregate([{ $match: { adminID: "1234" } }],"adminID roomID roomName users");
```

in new version second argument is selected fields in out put,

or use :

```
const data = await Rooms.aggregate.match({ adminID: "1234" } )
```